# JS Pick Random Quotes on Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making my website and I want it so that every time the user refreshes the page, a new random joke pops up instead of the previously picked one. This is the script I have right now:

```
function ShowJoke(){
  var Joke=["Jokes", "go", "here"];
  var Pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Joke.length));
  document.write(Joke[Pick]);
}
```

Comment: So you mean you want a random joke, but not one thats already been shown? That means its not random anymore.

Comment: `document.write`... hmmm.

Comment: Also, if you only have one joke, which other one you expect to be shown?

Comment: @trincot good point. My answer handles this. A set stored in localStorage is constantly updated and if there are no more jokes, then the randomization starts over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. But, you have syntax errors. Also, you are not calling the finction

```js
function ShowJoke()
  {
    var Joke = [
     'Joke1',
     'Joke2',
     'Joke3',
     'Joke4',
     'Joke5',
     'Joke6'
    ];
    var Pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Joke.length));
    document.write(Joke[Pick]);
  }
  
  document.addEventListener("load", ShowJoke());
```

Comment: this isn't correct. Function will be called immediately, not when the page loads.

Comment: "i want it so that every time the page refreshes a new random quote shows instead of the last one" - OP ; this does not do that. You still have the same chance to get the last joke.

Comment: @TyQ. My answer handles your need to not duplicate the jokes.

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer with the information you've given, so if something is wrong, please tell me so I can fix it.

So with what I'm taking from this question, you want to load a new joke on page load. "every time the page refreshes a new random quote shows instead of the last one"

Note: The below snippet might not work due to "allow-same-origin" flag and most likely will not work hosted locally unless you are using something like XAMPP.

The throwdown is to check to see if cookie exists, if it does, keep generating until a new joke is generated not equal to the cookie, set the new cookie, and display the joke.

```js
// Array of Jokes
var Jokes = [
"I just got fired from my job at the keyboard factory. They told me I wasn't putting in enough shifts.",
"We'll we'll we'll...if it isn't autocorrect.",
"Q. Which type of vegetable tries to be cool, but is only partly successful at it?\n\nA. The radish.",
"The world tongue-twister champion just got arrested. I hear they're gonna give him a really tough sentence."
];

// function to check cookie (true if exists, false if not)
function checkCookie(){
    var joke = getCookie();
    if (joke != "") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
// set the cookie so can be referenced later
function setCookie(cvalue){
    var cname = "joke";
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
// actually acquire the cookie and read it
function getCookie() {
    var cname = "joke";
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function ShowJoke(){
  let randomNum = ~~(Math.random() * Jokes.length); // pick a random number from 0 to length of jokes
  if(checkCookie()){ // check if cookie exists
    while(Jokes[randomNum] != getCookie()) randomNum = ~~(Math.random() * Jokes.length);
    } // while cookie's joke != generated joke
  document.getElementById('Joke').textContent = Jokes[randomNum]; // set content
  setCookie(Jokes[randomNum]); // set cookie
}
window.onload = ShowJoke(); // run on window load
```

```html
<p id="Joke"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix the typos

```
function ShowJoke()
  {
    var Joke=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    var Pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Joke.length));
    document.write(Joke[Pick]);
  }
```

and to actually call the function

```
ShowJoke();
```

EDIT:

It turns out that the op does not want to repeat the same joke, therefore we could do something like this:

```
function ShowJoke()
  {
    var RawJoke=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    var ToldJokes = localStorage.getItem("jokes");
    if (ToldJokes) {
        ToldJokes = JSON.parse(ToldJokes);
    } else {
        ToldJokes = [];
    }
    var Joke = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < RawJoke.length; i++)
        if (ToldJokes.indexOf(RawJoke[i]) === -1) 
            Joke.push(RawJoke[i]);
    if (Joke.length === 0) {
        ToldJokes = [];
        Joke = RawJoke;
    }
    var Pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Joke.length));
    ToldJokes.push(Joke[Pick]);
    localStorage.setItem("jokes", JSON.stringify(ToldJokes));
    document.write(Joke[Pick]);
  }
```

Comment: Good answer btw. I like how you utilize localStorage and not just sessionStorage.